# toastrjs - renew timer after hovering

Tags: javascript, toastr

I can't find any right way to renew timer in `toastrjs` after hovering.
I determinate a `extendedTimeOut` to 0, to not close the `toastr` when I hover over it.
The timeOut of `toastr` is 10000 ms, but when I'm finished hovering, `toastr` is immediately getting hide.
What's the right way to show a `toastr` 10000 ms after I'm finished hovering over it.

Example of my toastr properties:

```
const inboxToastr = toastr;
inboxToastr.info(data.bubbleData, title, {
    "tapToDismiss": false,
    "closeButton": true,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left", //position
    "preventDuplicates": false,
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "10000",
    "extendedTimeOut": "0",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "iconClass": "background-gray"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timeout 10000 and extendedTimeOut 10000 with other options to default seems to work as you expect, auto close after after 10 sec, keep shown while hovering and hide 10 sec after hovering out.

```js
$(function() {
  toastr.info("Title", 'Subtitle', {
    timeOut: 10000,
    extendedTimeOut: 10000,
    progressBar: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: It's not work for me. Maybe because this param is disable close on hover, and not close after hover....